# Install mongodb 2.6 with homebrew

Tags: installation, homebrew, version, mongodb

How can I install mongodb 2.6 with homebrew?

Here is what I am trying:

```
oobarbazanoos-MacBook-Pro:~ oobarbazanoo$ brew install mongodb@26
Error: No available formula with the name "mongodb@26" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow

Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
==> Searching local taps...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
oobarbazanoos-MacBook-Pro:~ oobarbazanoo$
```

Comment: MongoDB 2.6 was released in March, 2014 and reached [end of life in October, 2016](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-2-6-end-of-life). It is no longer available via Homebrew or supported by MongoDB, but if you really require this release series you can [download the 2.6.12 tarball](http://downloads.mongodb.org/osx/mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.6.12.tgz) from the MongoDB archives. Are there reasons you can't install a later version  of MongoDB? Also, what specific version of OS X are you running?

Comment: @Stennie, thank you for the attention. I am running High Sierra 10.13.2.

Comment: If there is a specific reason you need to install MongoDB 2.6 I suggest posting a question on DBA StackExchange with more details and any questions or concerns. For example, if you have existing MongoDB 2.6 data files you should be able to use those with newer versions of MongoDB (at least up to MongoDB 3.6) but perhaps with some caveats. Newer versions of MongoDB have more strict validation of collection and index options, and the authentication schema has also changed since MongoDB 2.6. You should have fewer issues with a supported version of MongoDB.

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB 2.6 was released in March, 2014 and reached [end of life in October, 2016](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-2-6-end-of-life). It is no longer available via Homebrew or supported by MongoDB, but if you *really* require this release series you can [download the 2.6.12 OS X tarball](http://downloads.mongodb.org/osx/mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.6.12.tgz) from the MongoDB archives.

End of life server releases will not receive any maintenance or security updates, and will also end up removed from driver and tool compatibility testing. I would strongly recommend installing a later supported version of MongoDB (ideally 3.4 or newer so you won't have to do a major version upgrade for a while). There have been a large number of [improvements and fixes in successive releases](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/), including a new default storage engine (WiredTiger), new aggregation & security features, document validation, and rewritten command line tools.

FYI, you can check available versions in Homebrew with `brew search mongodb@`:

> $ brew search mongodb@
>
> ==> Searching local taps...
>
> mongodb@3.0         mongodb@3.2         mongodb@3.4         mongodb@3.6